# Fatal error: Call to undefined function geturl() in Z:\home\mysitebiz.ru\www\searche\index.php on line 68

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, phpstorm, php7, php5

Здравствуте, после запуска кода браузер пишет следущее:  Fatal error: Call to undefined function geturl() in Z:\home\mysitebiz.ru\www\searche\index.php on line 68. Вот 68 линия: https://github.com/1yaroslav/monitoring-sites/blob/main/index.php#L68 , там и весь код.

P.S  Если честно я сам не знаю, что такое geturl. Т.к переписывал код с очень старой книги: Кузнецов "PHP 5. Практика создания веб-сайтов" 1 идание 2005 год...

Comment: Вы забыли "переписать/дописать" сам метод `geturl()`. Проверьте в источнике, где-то должна быть вызываемая функция `geturl()`

Comment: @Arsen точно! Спасибо большое! Я же код не до конца дописал!!

Comment: Там в конце ещё эта функция должнна быть

Comment: Этот вопрос решён